# Show empty series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I can't seem to show the series with empty data into my highcharts. I have some check-ins in a graph for each of the 7 weekdays. But when a day doesn't have data, it's hidden. What I would like to do is show the label of the empty serie on the x-axis (print the weekday name). I tried to populate my data with null values, using different options for highcharts, ...

I also can't set the color for the columns, I tried setting it to gray but that doesn't work.

Here's a demo in [JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/FdYnJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` for yAxis, instead of `minPadding` and `maxPadding`, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/tgZcc/21/

Comment: Lovely! That does the job. One final question: any idea how to color the bars? Adding the color option when creating the series doesn't work (I tried this in the jsfiddle)